# Changing space between text and itemized list

Tags: spacing, itemize, enumitem, line-spacing

I have a document with the following format:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Abc

Xyz
\vspace{-12pt}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
\setlength{\itemsep}{-1mm}
\item Bullet Point 1
\item Bullet Point 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I'd like the vertical distance between 'Xyz' and 'Bullet Point 1' to be equivalent to the vertical distance between 'Abc' and 'Xyz', but I'm not sure what the value of `\vspace` should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `nosep`?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
Abc

Xyz
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
\item Bullet Point 1
\item Bullet Point 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]